# HttpsURLConnection cannot get responds on Android

Tags: android, httpsurlconnection

I use below code to connect URL:

```
        URL url = new URL(URLPath);
        HttpsURLConnection HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");

        InputStream respondsStream = connection.getInputStream();
```

But I get error on line `InputStream respondsStream = connection.getInputStream();` as below:

```
04-11 14:16:11.445: W/System.err(26576): java.io.FileNotFoundException: URLPath
04-11 14:16:11.445: W/System.err(26576):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
04-11 14:16:11.445: W/System.err(26576):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)
```

But if I try to type the URLPath in browser, it can get responds success.
I confirm the network is works.
How to modify my code to avoid error?

Comment: What's the value of `URLPath`?

Comment: My own api server url(https://xxx/xxx/xxx).

Comment: Correct, but we need to see the real value of that.

Comment: But the url only used on lan.

Comment: You're URL is probably malformed, that's why I'm asking for the value you're putting there, otherwise it will hard to help.

Comment: So it maybe is the server's issue?

Comment: No, it's evidently a issue with your `URLPath`.

Comment: But the URLPath in my code and connect by browser are same.

Comment: It might not be the same, browsers add missing things for you, which obviously your code won't. I insist, without knowing this value I'll be guessing blindly.

Comment: The path like: https://ip/me/user/info?access_token=NTQxNjZiYzZmNjM0YmQ1ZTE5YmUxMTY0